# Convert google TimeOfDay object to string in laravel - php

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, google-my-business-api

I'm working with [timePeriod](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations#timeperiod) object with gmb library

I receive this response

```
0 => array:3 [▼
  "weekday" => "SUNDAY"
  "start_time" => {#11764 ▼
    +"hours": 10
  }
  "end_time" => {#11740 ▼
    +"hours": 21
  }
]
```

`start_time` and `end_time` key can have

```
{
  "hours": integer,
  "minutes": integer,
  "seconds": integer,
  "nanos": integer
}
```

I want to format that time to this format:

```
0 => array:3 [▼
    "weekday" => "SUNDAY"
    "start_time" => "10:00"
    "end_time" => "21:00"
  ]
```

Sometimes I get an empty array in `start_time` or `close_time` because it represent `0` hours (midnight)

```
0 => array:3 [▼
"weekday" => "SUNDAY"
"start_time" => []
"end_time" => {#13543 ▼
  +"hours": 24
}
]
```

I want to transform that to:

```
0 => array:3 [▼
"weekday" => "SUNDAY"
"start_time" => "00:00"
"end_time" => "24:00"
]
```

It is possible by using carbon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon won't be needed, it's fairly easy to do with pure PHP:

```
$data = [
  "weekday" => "SUNDAY",
  "end_time" => (object) ["hours" => 10],
  "start_time" => (object) ["hours" => 21],
];
$data['start_time'] = str_pad($data['start_time']->hours ?? 0, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' .
    str_pad($data['start_time']->minutes ?? 0, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$data['end_time'] = str_pad($data['end_time']->hours ?? 0, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' .
    str_pad($data['end_time']->minutes ?? 0, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Value of `$data` is now:

```
[
  "weekday" => "SUNDAY"
  "end_time" => "10:00"
  "start_time" => "21:00"
]
```

It is for hours:minutes as asked in your post, but it can have also seconds and nanoseconds following the same principle.